# How do I remove the [empty] right below category archives?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, archive

Been trying to google for answers but to no prevail.

http://puu.sh/4ir5w.jpg

and here's how it looks like under archives.php:

http://puu.sh/4kcJr.png

I've tried deleting the empty lines but it just leads to a parse error. And this is on a Wordpress site. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you better edit the functions which return the descriptions....but for a quick & dirty fix - try this one:

```
if( !empty($category_description) && $category_description !== '[empty]' )
//...

if( !empty($tag_description) && $tag_description !== '[empty]' )
//...
```

Comment: Well that didn't work :( I tried to edit the functions but could not find any related code or word related to [empty]

I tried the quick fix but got another: 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

Comment: =\ You just have to update the if-statements in lines 6 & 13(?) from your screenshot. Shouldn't return a parse-error. Really.

Comment: Like so? http://puu.sh/4kg7c.png

Because that's what I did before actually.

and it still gave me the Parse error

Comment: Please _replace_ both lines in your code with the matching lines from my example, instead of just adding things to the end of your lines. Right now you have an odd ')' before both '&&'. → The ')' causes the error.

Comment: Okay I did exactly what you said but it didn't change anything. The [empty] is still there, and I have deleted my cache to refresh what I changed. Do you have another code or something? :/
Also when I hover over the [empty], it says "Term Description" if that has any relevance.

Comment: Hum... If you only want to remove it, you could comment it out. To do this just add these two green elements to your code, right where i did: http://i42.tinypic.com/fmugzb.jpg (It's "Slash Asterisk" and "Asterisk Slash")

Comment: Perfect, that was what i needed. Cheers and I appreciate for sticking through with me the entire time. Thank you again!